# multiple combinations of one column based on another

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table like this (all my id2s are different) :

```
id1     id2
---     ---
A       1
A       2
B       3
C       4
```

and I want to generate a list of combinations of id2 for each distinct item of id1.

In this case, I would have had : **((1,3,4),(2,3,4))**.

Of course id1 is not limited to 3 items, it can be less/more, and I would like the SQL query or Python script to work whatever the number of distinct items in id1 is.

Example :

```
id1     id2
---     ---
A       1
A       2
B       3
B       4
C       5
D       6
```

will give : **((1,3,5,6),(1,4,5,6),(2,3,5,6),(2,4,5,6))**

and so on.

Either a MySQL script (ie. before it is loaded into Python) or a Python code snippet (once the raw table is loaded) is fine.

Comment: Is `id1` sorted, or at least doesn't contain the same item in several different chunks (like `['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']`?

Comment: @Timus i can make it sorted with an ASC in the SQL query : id1 can repeat, but as id2 is unique, the couple (id1,id2) won't never repeat --> look at my - own - answer

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm proud of me (LOL) I found something not bad.   ;-)

'compte' is a SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id1) FROM my_table

'combis' are all my combinations (eg. [(A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 3), (B, 4), (C, 5), (D, 6)]

```
# i generate my own list comprehension

for k in range(compte):
    toto = 'a'+str(k)+'[1]' + ( ',' if k != 0 else '' ) + toto
    titi = 'for a'+str(k)+' in combis ' + titi
    tutu = 'a'+str(k)+'[0]' + ( '>' if k != 0 else '' ) + tutu

exec('print([['+toto+'] '+titi+'if '+tutu+'])')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the id-data comes in the following form:

```
combis = [('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 4), ('C', 5), ('D', 6)]
```

Then

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

groups = defaultdict(list)
for id1, id2 in combis:
    groups[id1].append(id2)
result = list(product(*groups.values()))
```

produces

```
[(1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with combinationTable as (
 select DENSE_RANK() over (Order By id1) as rn ,id2, id1 from test
)
select c1.id2,c2.id2,c3.id2
from combinationTable c1, combinationTable c2, combinationTable c3
where
 c1.rn < c2.rn and
 c2.rn < c3.rn
order by c1.rn,c2.rn,c3.rn
```

Of course the "From clause" and "Where clause" will be modified if you want to choose 4 id2 instead of 3

Comment: thanks for your answer but precisely i want it to adapt itself no matter the number of DISTINCT id1s