# list of combination in sql

Tags: sql

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 4 |

This is the table and i want the list of combinations which i achieved using below code

```
with combinationTable as (
 select DENSE_RANK() over (Order By id1) as rn ,id2, id1 from test
)
select c1.id2,c2.id2,c3.id2
from combinationTable c1, combinationTable c2, combinationTable c3
where
 c1.rn < c2.rn and
 c2.rn < c3.rn
order by c1.rn,c2.rn,c3.rn
```

But i need to optimize the code instead of hard coding, in case if there are 4 or 5 distinct id1 then there should be 4 or 5 columns of id2 and 4 or 5 times cross joins of combinationtable.
how do we select columns and cross joins depending on distinct count of id1 column in an optimized way

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: You cannot do this with a single query.  What you are suggesting would have a variable number of columns, and a SQL query has a fixed number of columns.

Comment: I'm guessing MySQL, as it seems to be related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429242/multiple-combinations-of-one-column-based-on-another)

Comment: What is the desired result for that sample data?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

To re-create your query with dynamic columns, I can think of a way using [Prepared Stement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html):

```
SET @cols = NULL;
SET @tables = NULL;
SET @conditions = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SET @cols := (WITH RECURSIVE wo AS (
SELECT 1 idx, COUNT(DISTINCT id1) mxct FROM mytable 
UNION ALL
SELECT idx+1, mxct FROM wo WHERE idx+1 <= mxct)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('c',idx,'.id2')) FROM wo);

SET @tables := (WITH RECURSIVE wo AS (
SELECT 1 idx, COUNT(DISTINCT id1) mxct FROM mytable 
UNION ALL
SELECT idx+1, mxct FROM wo WHERE idx+1 <= mxct)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('combinationTable c',idx) SEPARATOR ' CROSS JOIN ') FROM wo);

SET @conditions := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(conds SEPARATOR ' AND ')
FROM
(WITH RECURSIVE wo AS (
SELECT 1 idx, COUNT(DISTINCT id1) mxct FROM mytable 
UNION ALL
SELECT idx+1, mxct FROM wo WHERE idx+1 <= mxct)
SELECT CONCAT('c',idx,'.rn < c',LAG(idx) OVER (ORDER BY idx DESC),'.rn') conds
FROM wo 
ORDER BY idx) A
WHERE conds IS NOT NULL);

SET @sql := (
CONCAT('WITH combinationTable AS (
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id1) AS rn ,id2, id1 FROM mytable
)
SELECT ',@cols,'
FROM ',@tables,'
WHERE ',@conditions,';'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The end query will be similar to you query above but with temp tables and columns dynamically generated by to total rows in the current table. All which being set to their own variables. You can see more of what the variables value in the [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5650c747a7d8c7017f1467d2a233820c)